# MATLAB - In FindPeaks, how is 'MinPeakProminence' different from 'Threshold'?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have written a code in Matlab R2017a, where to detect peaks, I used MinPeakProminence. Now I need to shift the code to Matlab 2014, where MinPeakProminence doesn't exist, while theres in another option called 'Threshold'. But for some reason, it doesn't give out the same results as MinPeakProminence.

How are they both different? What should I be doing to get the same result of MinPeakProminence in Matlab 2014?

Comment: When using MinPeakProminence Matlab will compare neighbouring peaks and just give you the most important once to the specified level. When using a Threshhold, matlab doesn't compare neighbouring peaks but just neighbouring data points and just return the peak if the neighbouring data points have at least the difference you defined.

Comment: by the way: are you using R2014 a or b? Because I think they introduced MinPeakProminence in R2014b

Comment: Must be a because it does up an error when I use that line of code. So, what can be done to achieve a similar result? @Max

Comment: You could try to run the 2017a findpeaks function with the 2014 version. Open the 2017 function with  `edit findpeaks`, give it a slighly different name and save it as a .m file. Then run it in 2014 and see what happens.

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger Thanks for the awesome idea! I tried but, it failed maybe because the function itself calls other newer functions which my version doesn't recognize

Comment: Yeah, I feared this would be the case, but it was worth a shot. Personally I think your only option (beside upgrading the 2014 version...) is to calculate the prominence of each point yourself. http://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html#buff2uu explains nicely how it is calculated. Remember, you can also use `findpeaks` to find the local minima.